# Cannot access C shared library methods from C++ code

Tags: android, c++, c

I'm trying to include a C library in my C++ code.

The C code has been compiled in to a C library. The C part is below:

This is the Android.mk file from the C component:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= logger.c
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu99

    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcutils libsysutils
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

    LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := company_name
    LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true
    LOCAL_MODULE := liblogger
    LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The header file (c_logger.h) from the C layer is below:

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus
int     logger_init ();
#if defined (__cplusplus)
}
#endif // __cplusplus
```

The logger.c implementations is below:

```
int combilog_init ()
{
    // logic
    return 0;
}
```

Im my CPP code, Android.mk, I've included this C library in "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES":

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblogger
```

Then I'm accessing it in my CPP code as:

```
int ret = init();
```

While compiling, I'm seeing the following error:

```
In file included from xxxx/Logger.cpp:20:
XXXX/CPP_Logger.h:26:10: fatal error: 'c_logger.h' file not found
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven’t told the compiler where it can find `logger.h`.

Comment: Do you really have two files one called Logger.h and another logger.h?  The error is reported for line 26 of XXXX/Logger.h, but none of the code you have included in the question relates to that.  The entire (re)build log - verbatim - would help - it would show the modules used and the command line options being used rather then trying to infer them from the make file content without knowledge of your build environment.

Answer (score 0):

you still need to include the matching .h so the compiler recognizes your init function

Comment: Are you mentioning about including the header file from the C library in the CPP code?

Comment: @webgenius : The compiler has to be able to see the `extern "C"` declaration in your first fragment "undeclared identifier" means that it can't.  It is hard to determine why that might be because you have elided the error message and code fragments and have omitted information regarding the location of the code fragments.  Error messages normally include information such as the file being compiled and the line number the error occurs at - that is important diagnostic information you have also omitted.

Comment: @Clifford My bad. I've edited the original question to have all the details.